# rails ajax overwriting all partials when refreshing page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I was making a simple variation of the simple example of ajax in rails: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#a-simple-example

I am trying to create a user show view in which new posts are created upon pressing a button. These posts are all listed below the user on the same show page and appear upon creation.

The posts are created fine and shown correctly on the page, however when I refresh the page my

```
  @post = User.posts.build()
```

Overwrites all the previously created posts giving each of them a nul id.
Also, is it correct to place the create.js.erb in the views folders, or should it go in the assets/javascripts folder?

Here are my files:

UsersController

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @posts = Post.all
    @post = @user.posts.build
end
```

users/show.html.erb

```
<%= "user-id: #{@user.id}" %>

<ul id="posts">
<%= render :partial => @posts %>
</ul>


<%= form_for(@post, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => @user.id %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

PostsController

```
def create
  puts params[:post][:user_id]
  @user = User.find(params[:post][:user_id])
  puts @user
  @post = @user.posts.build()
  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
      format.js   {}
      format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
    Rails.logger.info(@post.errors.inspect) 
  end
end

def index
    @posts = Post.all
    @post = Post.new
end
```

posts/_post.html.erb

```
 <li><%= @post.id %></li>
```

posts/create.js.erb

```
 $("<%= escape_javascript(render @post) %>").appendTo("#posts");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The Problem

The reason why your partial is rendering all new posts is because you are using the *instance variable* `@post` instead of the *local variable* `post` inside your partial.

In your `UsersController#show` action, you set `@post = @user.posts.build`. When you render `<%= @post.id %>` inside the partial, you are referencing that same variable which comes from the controller and was set to a new post.

It *seems* that all the previously created posts are being "null'ed" out, but it's really just that you are continuously rendering a new post, not the existing ones.

## The Solution

You need to update your partial to use a *local variable*, not the *instance variable*.

```
<li><%= post.id %></li>
```

This local variable is automatically provided to you by Rails when you render a collection of records like this

```
<%= render @user.posts %>
```

or alternatively

```
<%= render partial: "posts/post", collection: @user.posts %>
```

## How to Avoid in the Future

This is a *really common* mistake and can be easy to miss.

For this reason, my recommendation is to [stop using instance variables in partials](http://www.carlosramireziii.com/stop-using-instance-variables-in-partials.html?utm_source=stackoverflow) altogether.

## Resources

- [Rails Guides - Rendering Collections](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections)
- [Stop Using Instance Variables In Partials](http://www.carlosramireziii.com/stop-using-instance-variables-in-partials.html?utm_source=stackoverflow)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I'll make it a rule to avoid instance variables in partials

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround by avoiding the use of the _post partial to display the older posts:

edit: users/show.html.erb

```
<ul id="posts">
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <li>
      <%= post.id %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

I don't think this is an ideal solution but it works fine for now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct.

`create.js.erb` with the suffix `erb` to help you add code ruby to it.

Write code in this file the same with you write javascript code on view `html.erb` with syntax

```
<script>
  $("<%= escape_javascript(render @post) %>").appendTo("#posts");
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, do you understand why my list of posts all become Post.new upon refreshing the page?

Comment: on posts_controller/index
What does  **@post = Post.new** means?

Comment: I have deleted that since it was a mistake, but the user show view still displays each post as Post.new instead of separate posts

Comment: I think you should move file ```posts/_post.html.erb``` and ```posts/create.js.erb``` under folder ```views/users```